# Gitlab repository size is too high

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project hosted on GitLab and this project is too huge, cf attached printscreen. [Gitlab repository size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwhCG.png).

As this Gitlab project is about 4Gb, it takes too long time to fetch the entire project with a bad internet connection...

I've tried the procedure described on [this page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html) :

```
  git clone --bare --mirror https://gitlab.example.com/my/project.git
  git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
  git filter-repo --blob-callback '
  if blob.data.startswith(b"version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1"):
    size_in_bytes = int.from_bytes(blob.data[124:], byteorder="big")
    if size_in_bytes > 10*1000:
      blob.skip()
  '
git push origin --force 'refs/heads/*
```

After the `push`, there is no changes on my repository...

Do you have an idea to reduces it ?
Thanks

Comment: Why is it so large?

Comment: Double check you haven't committed any binaries, node_modules, compiled files etc. We may need to see your source to help further.

Comment: @James Thanks for the help, I will try to remove all saved artifacts...
If you want to see the repository details : https://gitlab.com/arnauddm/docarchiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing old pipelines and artifacts, I've succeed to free up space.
If in the future, someone has the same "problem", I've used [this script](https://gist.github.com/carceneaux/b75d483e3e0cb798ae60c424300d5a0b)